# Run HTML inside a Text box

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to be able to run a html code with javascript inside a text box.  Just like they do it at w3schools.com .  I'm only using html and javascript no other languages. Thank you

Example: I have two text areas one where we insert html and click a button and run the html and it displays in the other text area.

I found some code that might make this happen but can not get it to work.  I'm using chrome if that helps.

Here is the link to the basic code where i went to get this from.
http://forgottengamer.blogspot.com/2013/01/make-html-editor-like-w3schools-try-it.html

Here is a link to my code

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pT2SVBaUkqeZo5n3ow76HDrG3OzO6zzohUFH6r6RCJY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you explain further and post some code

Comment: It's called a contentEditable iframe.

Comment: Just document.write("some code")

Comment: ok well I will do a search on that thank you Mouser

Comment: Why not just use http://codepen.io/ or http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you'll need to do the following

- Create a textbox where user will enter its HTML content.
- On submit, create a dynamic iframe with dynamically inserting the DOM from the HTML of the user entered above.

This should be fairly easy ignoring the security measures. Upto you!